# Rails 3 queries - wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm currently converting my 2.3.8 rails app to 3.1.

Error:

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:22:in `footer'
```

Code:

```
@system_message = Constant.where(:key => "system_message").first
```

This error occurs with the **first** and **all** methods, on *any* model.

Even with these:

```
Episode.where(:id => 1).first
Episode.first
Episode.all
```

Setup:

- Ruby 1.9.2
- Rails 3.1.1.rc3

Gemfile:

```
source "http://rubygems.org"
source "http://gemcutter.org/"
source "http://gems.github.com/"

#Main
gem "rails", "3.1.1.rc3"
#gem "rails", :git => "git://github.com/rails/rails.git"

#System
gem "mysql2"
gem "therubyracer", require: "v8"

#Tools
gem "capistrano"
gem "hoptoad_notifier"
gem "whenever"

#Application
gem "jquery-rails"
gem "hpricot"
gem "ar-extensions"
gem "gravtastic"
gem "will_paginate"
gem "time_diff"
gem "has_permalink"

#Email
gem "adzap-ar_mailer"#, :lib => "action_mailer/ar_mailer"
gem "ambethia-smtp-tls"#, :lib => "smtp-tls"

#Devise
gem "devise"
gem "warden"

group :assets do
  gem "sass-rails",   "~> 3.1.4"
  gem "coffee-rails", "~> 3.1.1"
  gem "uglifier", ">= 1.0.3"
end

group :development do
  gem "bullet"
end

group :test do
  gem "turn", :require => false
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

The gem "ar-extensions" isn't supported for Rails 3.
Changed to the "activerecord-import" gem.